# Incorrect behavior of the scroll's indicator

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have `UIScrollView`. I set contentOffset using the code :

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    [comicsScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(comicsScrollView.contentOffset.x, currentView.frame.origin.y + currentView.bounds.size.height/2 - comicsScrollView.bounds.size.height/2) animated:NO];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     }];
```

Into

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

method and the same code into

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

When I make vertical scroll - scroll's indicator has an incorrect behavior, It jumps or remains in previous position.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The `setContentOffset` call can handle animation for you. Pass in `animated:YES` and lose the `UIView animationWithDuration:` block.

In other words, just try this:

```
[comicsScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(comicsScrollView.contentOffset.x,     
   currentView.frame.origin.y + currentView.bounds.size.height/2 -    
   comicsScrollView.bounds.size.height/2) animated:YES];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: It's a method not for my task, because it delay animation, what I mean: after scrolling [setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x,y) animated:YES] calls with delay, I need in a tick reaction.